# querying relational models in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In my Web Application I have three models. Namely- items,Manufacturers,items_manufacturers
This is the query I need to perform

```
SELECT items.id,item_desc,manufacturers.id,manufacturers.name FROM items_manufacturers,items,manufacturers WHERE items_manufacturers.item_id=item.id AND items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id=manufacturers.id
```

The relation between the models is

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'item' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Items', 'item_id'),
            'manufacturer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Manufacturers', 'manufacturer_id'),
            'itemsManufacturersLocations' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ItemsManufacturersLocations', 'items_manufacturer_id'),
        );
    }
```

I am unable to write this query using the conventions in Yii framework.
This is what I tried

```
$im=new CDbCriteria ;
$im->with= array(
           'items_manufacturers.item_id'
           'items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id'
           'items.item_desc'
           'manufacturers.manufacturer_name'
           'condition'=>'items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id=manufacturers.id 
                         items_manufacturer.item_id=items.id'
);
))->findAll();
```

Any body kindly help me with this, since I am new to this framework.I am stuck up with this.I tried this in the items_manufacturers Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning 'with' property with db columns, while you should do something like:

```
$im = new CDbCriteria;

$im->with = array('items','manufacturers'); // you put 'relation names' here, not db columns

$imf = ItemsManufacturers::model()->findAll($im);
```

You could do this without criteria:

```
$imf = ItemsManufacturers::model()->with('items','manufacturers')->findAll();
```

Comment: does it fetch when items.id=items_manufacturers.item_id and manufacturers.id=items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id ?

Comment: well, 'with' function makes a JOIN, so it does